# bigQuery log in issue

Tags: google-bigquery

I deleted my BigQuery project, now when I attempt to log in to create a new project, the welcome url changes to search for the project I deleted and does not render.  How do I remove that association from my account so I can log in and create new projects?

Comment: Did you try loading the Cloud Console and creating a project there? https://console.cloud.google.com/

Comment: Thank you, that worked...  much appreciated